# How to reuse Logstash codec or pattern definition?

Tags: logstash

### Background

Currently in my Logstash configuration, I have something like:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "catalina-out"
    path => [ "/var/tomcat/logs/catalina.out"]
    sincedb_path => "$HOME/.sincedb"
    tags => ["tomcat", "catalina-out"]
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "(^.+Exception: .+)|(^\s+at .+)|(^\s+... \d+ more)|(^\s*Caused by:.+)|(%{LOGLEVEL}: %{GREEDYDATA})"
    what => "previous"
    }
  }
...
```

### What I'm trying to accomplish

I have lots of Tomcat output files, and I would like to reuse this `codec` (or, less optimally, the `pattern`) with other `file` definitions.

### The problem

My problem is that the following gives me an error:

```
input {

  tomcat_multiline_codec => multiline {
    pattern => "(^.+Exception: .+)|(^\s+at .+)|(^\s+... \d+ more)|(^\s*Caused by:.+)|(%{LOGLEVEL}: %{GREEDYDATA})"
    what => "previous"
  }

  file {
    type => "catalina-out"
    path => [ "/var/tomcat/logs/catalina.out"]
    sincedb_path => "$HOME/.sincedb"
    tags => ["tomcat", "catalina-out"]
    codec => tomcat_multiline_codec
  }
...
```

### The question

How can I define the `codec` (or if necessary, the `pattern`) once, separately from the `file` block so I can reuse it in other `file` blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply isn't supported. Logstash doesn't have general-purpose variables. Unless you can  use a multiline *filter* your best bet would be to use a configuration management system with templating support to generate and deploy your Logstash configuration files. You shouldn't be maintaining them by hand anyway.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I ended up putting a `multiline` inside a conditional inside a `filter`, as you mentioned. We are using a templating system, but I'm trying to make do with the tools provided as much as possible for the sake of understanding it and keeping it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can push the catalina logs also directly to logstash using GELF: http://www.paluch.biz/blog/105-integrating-logstash-with-tomcat-7.html

See also [How can I integrate Tomcat6's catalina.out file with Logstash + ElasticSearch + Kibana?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429377/how-can-i-integrate-tomcat6s-catalina-out-file-with-logstash-elasticsearch)